# Error 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo la siguiente función que me arroja el error al descargar el archivo excel:

> 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed.

```
 async function exportExcel(page) {
        //Se obtienen filtros de busqueda
        var type_bussiness = $('#type_bussiness_find option:selected').val();
        var find_text = $('#find_name').val();
        var license_text = $('#find_license').val();

        var per_page = $("#per_page").val();
        var parametros = {
            "page": page,
            'type_bussiness': type_bussiness,
            'text': find_text,
            'license': license_text,
            'per_page': per_page,
            'type': 'company'
        };
        await $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "./?action=export_excel",
            data: parametros,
            beforeSend: function(data) {
                $("#loader").html("<img src='res/images/ajax-loader.gif'>");
            },
            xhrFields:{responseType: 'blob'},
            //console.log(data);
            success: function(data) {
                //console.log(data);
                let today = new Date();
                let dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
                let mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
                let yyyy = today.getFullYear();
                today = `${mm}_${dd}_${yyyy}`;
                var blob = data;
                var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                a.href = downloadUrl;
                a.download = `Empresas_${today}.xlsx`;
                a.target = '_blank';
                a.click();
                $("#loader").html("");
            }

        });
    }
```

Lo extraño es que en mi servidor local funciona, pero en el servidor de pruebas no lo hace.  Al parecer la función createObjectURL está deprecated, pero no se porque no funciona igual en ambos servidores dentro del mismo navegador.

el archivo que se envía se hace con la librería php excel con lo siguiente:

```
  ob_end_clean();
  header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="planilla.xls"');
  header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
  header("Pragma: no-cache");
  header("Expires: 0");

  $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
  $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: Hola, usa new URL(blob) en su lugar, saludos.

Comment: var downloadUrl = new URL(blob); así? no funciona de esa manera

Comment: ¿Cual se supone que es el valor de `data` ? ¿No estarás recibiendo una cadena? Es probable que necesites hacer algo como [`var blob = new Blob([bytes], options)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob)

Comment: @Marcos data trae un documento excel

Comment: Tienes razón, por ahí leí que createobjecturl no soporta más blob

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar el resultado de `console.log(data)` (_como texto_)?

Comment: @marcos como dije trae un documento excel 2007 con datos formateados ilegibles

Comment: No hace falta que sea un archivo real (_con info sensible_), puede ser un archivo vació. La idea es que nos des toda la info necesaria para reproducir el error y poder ayudarte a encontrar una solución.

Comment: es un archivo creado con php excel mediante el codigo que adjuntaré en la pregunta original